# How to change the voice language to english?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I recently bought Dragon Age: Inquisition and I'm keen on playing it. I do have a German client, so the voice is set to German on standard.

In the ingame settings I'm able to change the text language to English, but not the voice.

I can read on the Interwebs that Bioware released a free DLC which enables English voice audio, but I really can't find where to activate that DLC. Several sites claim that there is a DLC section in the Origin-window, but I can't find it:

[image]

**How can I activate the English voice language on another localized client?**

Comment: That answer looks neat, but as you can see on my screenshot I can't find any DLC to select... I therefore need an instruction to find that.

Comment: @Trollwut - if it doesn't exist, then it doesn't exist. Best we can do is point you there, and if you still have problems, you should email Bioware or Origin.

Comment: So it has to be where my screenshot is? Because then I'll email them. I'm just not used to Origin, so maybe I just missed something. :)